# How do I emulate a shell script's "expect" function in std::process::Command?

Tags: rust, sh

I am trying to create a function that installs homebrew by running `install.sh` using `std::process::Command`:

```
let output = Command::new("bash")
    .arg("install.sh")
    .output()
    .expect("brew install failed");

println!("command output: {:?}", output);
```

This prints the following output, which is a prompt asking for the user's password, in this case mine.

```
command output: "==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).\nNeed sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user blah needs to be an Administrator)!\n"
```

How do I pass in the password to the command and continue with the installation? Basically, I am looking for a way to emulate the shell script's `expect` function using the `Command` struct. Is it possible?

Comment: What `expect` does is to allocate a pseudo-terminal (pty) and redirect the reading half it to the stdin of the shell; then it writes the user input to the writing half of the pty. Maybe it is easier just to call `expect` directly or even setup the `sudoers` file to not need a password for this particular command?

Comment: I would also recommend just shelling out to `expect`, as properly interacting with the two sides (stdin/stdout) of an interactive subprocess tends to be rather tricky.

Comment: Yes, I have thought of using expect directly and modify the install.sh, but still curious if this is possible with Command. Using the wait_with_output function allows the previous command to proceed and ask for the password, but I would like it to fetch or receive the password automatically and continue with the installation without asking.

Comment: Yes it's possible: use [`spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn) instead of `output`, then use the [`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#fields) of the returned child to interact with it.

Comment: Or use the [`rexpect` crate](https://crates.io/crates/rexpect).

Comment: It appears your question is answered by [Write to child process' stdin in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49218599/155423) or [How to send input to a program through stdin in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21615188/155423)